# Where to I put my import.sql file, not sure where the root of my class path is?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

In my hibernate properties in my servlet-context.xml I have:

```
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            hibernate.query.substitutions=true 'Y', false 'N'
            hibernate.show_sql=true
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
        </value>
    </property>
```

And I read that I can seed my database if I put my import.sql file in the root of my class path.

Im' using IntelliJ, where would the root of my classpath be?  Is it where I set the source path for my module?

i.e.

```
/src/main/java
```

Ideally what I want is also to have a import.sql run for my test cases also, probably have that in a seperate file, is that a job for something like ant?

Comment: Where did you read about this?

Answer (score 4):

It looks likes you are using maven from your source path. So you should put it in

```
src/main/resources/
```

This is the root of your classpath. You can also check to see what the root is by opening a debugger and running

```
getClass().getResource("/")
```

Comment: or `src/test/resources/` for tests

Answer (score 3):

To define the import file location, you may set this property

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files
```

Default is

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files="/import.sql"
```

To load multiple sql files, just separate them whith comma, like

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files="/scripts/business.sql,/scripts/security.sql"
```

Regards!